# Dynamic datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

In a Dataset I have a datatable. This datable can be divided in a certain number of cycles ( defined by a function).
After finding the cycles I want to generate Datable for each cycles. So my question is to know how to declare dynamically Datable ?

Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with your programming language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but if I understand you correctly, would this be the sort of thing you are looking to do??

```
DataSet cyclesDataSet = new DataSet("Cycles");
someclass.CycleComplete(cyclesDataSet, "C1");
.
.
.
public void CycleComplete(DataSet dataset, String cycleId)
{
    var cycleTable = dataset.Tables.Add("cycleId");
    // Manipulate table here.
}
```

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: thanks, ok to be more precise I want to know how to create Datatable like Datatable_1 , Datatable_2,....,Datatable_N cycles ?

Comment: Why would you want to create separate variables for each cycle?  If you are storing them in a dataset, then there is surely no need to have them live outside of the dataset?  If you are looking to record the cycle Id in the datatable name, then just use a cycle counter of some sort to append to the datatable name, such as I did in the example.

Comment: yeah actually you are right your idea works perfectly. Thanks